# Run (java)script on dropdown change

Tags: javascript, content-management-system, pega

Hey all I am trying to run a javascript when the user selects a particular option.

I have **created a text file** by going to **Create -> Technical -> Text File**

Once I am there I fill out the needed info:

[image]

[image]

Then I click on **Create And Open**:
[image]

And so I **save** that and go back to my **layout** where I am wanting to **call it from thedropdown**:
[image]

[image]

So as you can see I am doing a **Run Script** which I **call the reqOnOrOff (I also tried just having yo) when the user selects the item called Tunable FFL**.

Once that is **saved** I go view that page in pega itself and open up the **console (F12)** and refresh the page and then **select Tunable FFL** from the **dropdown** and there is **no console text saying "hello"** as there should be.

[image]

[image]

The **harness**:

[image]

[image]

The **overall goal** is to be able to **dynamically** change a **textbox required propertieson** (it required to fill out) or **off** (it is not required to fill out).

Anyone that can help me fix this (or tell me what I am doing wrong) would be great!

Thanks

Comment: Why is it (java)script?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Becasuse when you select a componet (dropdown box) and add the "change" event the event is called "Run Script". This can run many scripts but I am only looking for the Javascript file I created to be accessable after the user changes an item in the dropdown box.

Comment: Did you include that js text file into your harness or application skin rule ? And try just giving the function name in Run Script Action.

Answer (score 0):

The value in the Action "Run Script" > Function name should be yo, not the name of the text file.

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically set if a text input is required, use 'conditional (expression)' or 'conditional (when rules)' option in either App Studio or Dev Studio.

In App Studio authoring, open the field properties. See:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgLfr.png

In Dev Studio, in your section open the cell properties. See:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r76mm.png